# Trying to fetch Youtube Trending videos name and links using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to fetch Youtube Trending videos into excel sheet with Title and video links. But my code is not working. I do not know whether there is something wrong with my code or the trending page.
This is code from where i am trying to video the data

```
    <a id="video-title" class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-video-renderer" aria-label="VIDEO TITLE & DETAILS" title="VIDEO TITLE" href="/watch?v=J2UuYHahPMI">VIDEO TITLE</a>
```

When i run the code. It just load the page and does nothing. It does not even show any error. I tried fetching data `"getElementbyID"` as well as with `"getElementsByClassName"`

Here is the screenshot from where i am trying to fetch the data.
[image]

```
Sub YOUTUBETREND()

Dim objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer 'special object variable representing the IE browser
Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement 'special object variable for an <a> (link) element
Dim y As Integer 'integer variable we'll use as a counter
Dim result As String 'string variable that will hold our result link

'initiating a new instance of Internet Explorer and asigning it to objIE
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

'make IE browser visible (False would allow IE to run in the background)
objIE.Visible = True

'navigate IE to this web page (a pretty neat search engine really)
objIE.navigate "https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending/"

'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

'the first search result will go in row 2
y = 2

'for each <a> element in the collection of objects with class of 'result__a'...
For Each aEle In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("yt-simple-endpoint")

    '...get the href link and print it to the sheet in col C, row y
    result = aEle
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & y).Value = result

    '...get the text within the element and print it to the sheet in col D
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & y).Value = aEle.innerText
    Debug.Print aEle.innerText

    'increment our row counter, so the next result goes below
    y = y + 1

'repeat times the # of ele's we have in the collection
Next
objIE.Quit
```

Comment: I cant read anything from your screenshot. The resolution is too low.

Comment: its resolution is 1,280px × 670px. Its just i inspected YouTube video title using firefox and its show the id and class. This is the code from where I want to fetch the data.     <a id="video-title" class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-video-renderer" aria-label="VIDEO TITLE & DETAILS" title="VIDEO TITLE" href="/watch?v=J2UuYHahPMI">VIDEO TITLE</a> –

Comment: Looking at your image, I can read `class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope ytd-video-renderer"` not only `"yt-simple-endpoint"`. Am I wrong?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns on the there website they are using 3 class. I am just using one of them to fetch the data. On other pages of youtube was always able to fetch data with one. I even tried with all the three class to fetch the data. Yet its not working.

Comment: Now that the picture is in the question the quality is okay. The previous link wasn't zoomable on mobile.

Comment: Are there more subs in your code?

Comment: @Luuklag No, there no other subs. This is all of it. it used to work before. When i try fetching with getElementbyId("video-title") it shows error - "object required".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not getting any errors then you must be using some error handling that's masking the error?

`result` has been dimensioned as a `String` type - but you're doing:

```
'...get the href link and print it to the sheet in col C, row y
result = aEle
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & y).Value = result
```

here, `aEle` is an object from a `HTMLCollection`, because you used `getElementsByClassName()`

You can't assign an object to a string, this should be throwing a Type Mismatch error.

Comment: No thr is no error handler. This is whole code which one using. I used same very code to fetch data from other youtube pages and website. But some how its not working on Youtube Trends. I don't know why. I picked this code from "http://automateexcel.com/".

Comment: I do not much about coding.But tthanks anyway for helping.